# What does this kanji 亏 mean?

Tags: kanji

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%8F#Japanese) this symbol 亏 is a Japanese kanji.

[Jisho](http://jisho.org/search/%E4%BA%8F) returns no results. Does anyone know what it means?

Comment: Could you share the link that shows 亏 is a Japanese character?  If you go to [Goo](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/cj/14835/meaning/m0u/亏/) you'll find an explanation (in Japanese) of it's meaning and  you'll find that it's only listed as a Chinese character (in fact a search of Goo shows no results in Japanese).

Comment: If you roll down, there is a title which says Japanese, Kanji 亏, (uncommon “Hyōgai” kanji) This term needs a translation to English. Readings
On: う (u)
Kun: かける (kakeru) https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%8F

Comment: My desk copy of 漢和中辞典 lists about 9500 characters.   亏 is not listed there.  9500 is certainly not an exhaustive listing of all characters ever used in Japan, but its lack of an entry there or in Goo certainly suggests this is quite an exceptional  character.  I wonder where wikitionary got its information.  Curiosity: why the interest in this character?

Comment: It's not Japanese indeed, it's a simplification of 虧 used in Chinese. I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [Chinese](http://cjjc.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BA%8F). 亏 is pronounced kuī (first tone), and it is a simplification of 虧 which I think you can actually also find in Japanese dictionaries and means to lower/to decrease or to lack (like 欠{か}ける). It also means "to wane" (speaking of the moon). Look [here](http://kanji.jitenon.jp/kanjil/5631.html) for more.

A sample sentence from the first link:

> 我亏了二百元 ＝ 私は200元損をした = I lost 200 yuan (Chinese currency).

Still I'm interested in seeing the wiki page stating it's Japanese, it might be a very uncommon if ever used and one should check a more comprehensive dictionary like the 大漢和辞典.

Comment: I think [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%8F#Japanese) got the readings from [Unihan](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=%E4%BA%8F). Don't know if there are any rules about which variants of hyōgai kanji to use in Japanese but my experience is that they use either traditional or shinjitai, not simplified Chinese variants.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a Japanese kanji. It's a Chinese character.

号 may be a Japanese kanji you were looking for. 
Or it might be a confusion with 云う（いう）（iu) .

Are you sure that it was really 亏 that you saw in Wikipedia?  :)